# Permitir caracteres especiales en .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

tengo un problema al momento de mostrar archivos pdf, en mi htaccess tengo esto:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?view=$1
```

Todo me esta funcionando bien, pero al momento de mandar una url como esta:

```
href="files/RAD.pdf/"
href="files/archivo.pdf/"
```

Allí se me presenta el problema y es que me manda a la pagina 404, de que la ruta no existe, creo que el problema esta en que mi htaccess no permite `.-_&()` o cualquier carácter especial. He estado buscando como hacer que me los permita pero sin éxito.

Y mi index.php lo tengo de esta forma para ir enlazando las vistas segun la url que vaya pasando:

```
 <?php

require('config/Config.php');

if (isset($_GET['view'])) {
  $views = explode("/",$_GET['view']);
  if ($views[0]=="admin") {
    $ruta = $views[1];
  } else {
    $ruta = $views[0];
  }

  if (is_file('enrutadores/'.$views[0].'/'.$ruta.'Enrutador.php')) {
    require('enrutadores/'.$views[0].'/'.$ruta.'Enrutador.php');
  } else {
    include('vistas/404.php');
  }
} else {
  include('enrutadores/indexEnrutador.php');
}

?>
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: por el `/` al final debe estar buscando una carpeta llamada "`files/RAD.pdf/`".

Comment: No. sin eso igualmente me manda a la pagina 404

Answer (score 1):

Esas *url's* lanzan error porque estás buscando rangos `a-zA-A`, `0-9`y `/`, pero si te fijas, la extensión del archivo incluye un punto (`.`).

Cambia el patrón añadiendo ese punto que falta y debería funcionar. Igual con el resto de caracteres que necesites incluir.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/.]+)$ index.php?view=$1
                         ^
```

*Nota: Si lo añades al final se toma como un punto literal. Cambiándolo de lugar se tomaría como un comodín permitiendo cualquier caracter, por lo que deberías escaparlo. Ejemplo:*

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\./]+)$ index.php?view=$1
                        ^^
```

Comment: Saludos Oscar, he probado con tu respuesta pero aun sigo con el mismo problema, incluso en todos los enlaces me manda a la pagina 404. Allí he editado la pregunta colocando mi archivo index.php el cual funciona de enrutador de las vistas según la url que vaya pasando.

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido solución a mi inquietud, estuve leyendo la documentacion de .htaccess y he dado con la forma de permitir los puntos en la url con htaccess para poder mostrar los archivos pdf que necesitaba.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?view=$1&file=$2
```

He agregado despues de la primera expresion `^([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)` lo siguiente:

```
/(.*)$
```

De esta forma me permitio entrar al archivo pdf y ademas pase una segunda variable get llamada `&file=$2` con eso he podido mostrar los archivos.